# Runge-Kutta method fourth order for orbits around the sun -- setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python-3.x, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I implemented the fourth-order runge-kutta method as I have always done, but this time gives me a Value error, I suppose it is for solving two differential equations using a function that returns an array of four elements.
Can someone tell me where I'm wrong please?
The equations to solve are as follows:

[image]

And my code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=6.674184*(10**-11)
M=1.9891*(10**30)


def f(r,t): #definition of equations
    x=r[0]
    z=r[1]
    y=r[2]
    z1=[3]
    R=np.sqrt((x**2)+(y**2))
    fx=z
    fz=-(G*M)*(x/(R**3))
    fy=z1
    fz1=-(G*M)*(y/(R**3))

    return(np.array([fx,fz,fy,fz1],float))

a=0
b=500
N=1000

time=np.arange(a,b,h)

r=np.array([4e12,0,0,500],float) #initial conditions

xpositions=[]
vel_x=[]
ypositions=[]
vel_y=[]

for t in time: #Runge-Kutta Method
    xpositions.append(r[0])
    vel_x.append(r[1])
    ypositions.append(r[2])
    vel_y.append(r[3])
    k1=h*f(r,t)
    k2=h*f(r+0.5*k1,t+(h*0.5))
    k3=h*f(r+0.5*k2,t+(h*0.5))
    k4=h*f(r+k3,t+h)
    r+=(1/6)*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)
```

Comment: "gives me a Value error" - please post the complete traceback

Comment: If I were Python, I'd give a `NameError`, because `h` is not defined here: `time=np.arange(a,b,h)`

Comment: You could use `R=np.hypot(x,y)`, why do you use these strange names for the velocities, what is with `vx,vy`? You could shorten the initial assignment to `x,vx,y,vy = r`. With your parameters, you probably want `time=np.linspace(a,b,N+1); h=time[1]-time[0];`

Comment: My h is (b-a)/N.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about h, but what I wanted with h was to create a "ruler" spaced by h.
I have already solved other differential equations with this method by making my h a vector, but this time it is giving me problems. I suppose to be giving 4 elements to the vector, whereas in previous programs it only gave two. I would really like to know a way to solve the problem. But thanks so much for the tips!

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann

Comment: i don't know how to put tracebak but it points me error to line 39 and 19. @ForceBru

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-7bbaef904db0> in <module>
     37     ypositions.append(r[2])
     38     vel_y.append(r[3])
---> 39     k1=h*f(r,t)
     40     k2=h*f(r+0.5*k1,t+(h*0.5))
     41     k3=h*f(r+0.5*k2,t+(h*0.5))

<ipython-input-20-7bbaef904db0> in f(r, t)
     17     fz1=-(G*M)*(y/(R**3))
     18 
---> 19     return(np.array([fx,fz,fy,fz1],float))
     20 
     21 a=0

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is the line

```
z1=[3]
```

Sometimes it helps to use a debugger or to at least print the variables that are in use in the error line.

The reported error is a follow-up of that, it happens because you try to use this array and the other float values to construct a numpy array. *" ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."* is a quite specific message.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I don't know how I hadn't noticed. Forever grateful @Dr. Lutz Lehmann